# What type of math uses congruence in spheres and was what I proved true?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, trigonometry

I used a good portion of my summer break to read about topology and I'm interested to know if what I proved was informally a method used in topology? If not what type of math did I employ to prove this.

I was given a problem to solve for an electrical field inside of a sphere with a empty space inside of it. The way to get to that derivation is unimportant to my question. The smaller sphere centered at H in the first figure is hollow.

[image]

I found that this sphere was ≅ with this other sphere:

[image]

Then I found that this sphere was ≅ with this other sphere:

[image]

I got to the right answer and it makes complete sense to me, but I would like to do more reading on this topic as it seems to be an important one. What type of geometry or topology did I use to solve this? Is it an argument of symmetry?

Comment: This is not topology nor even trigonometry, this looks instead like congruences in ordinary Euclidean geometry. However, since you are not specific about what is being proved congruent to what, your question is unclear.

Comment: I shifted the smaller empty sphere within the bigger sphere to the center and said those two sphere were congruent. Then I cut out the empty sphere in the center of that sphere and said a sphere of radius H was congruent to the other two spheres.

Comment: The justification for this is the superposition principle of electic fields. The charge distribution can be though of as the sum of two charged spheres with opposite signs. The electic field is then just the sum of the electric fields created by each sphere (see e.g. [this derivation](http://jkwiens.com/2007/10/24/answer-electric-field-of-a-nonconducting-sphere-with-a-spherical-cavity/)).